# Swift PhysicsBody not affected by Impulse

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, game-physics

this is my first post here and i am new to iOS programming. I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 to build my practice game. All i want is i want to jump the ball when the screen is tapped but the impulse is not working. Here is the code i have written.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var footBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sfb")
var Score = 0
var GameStarted = false


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    footBall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    footBall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    footBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: footBall.frame.height / 2)
    footBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    footBall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    footBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    self.addChild(footBall)
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(GameStarted == false){
        GameStarted = true
        footBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        footBall.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        footBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))
    }
    else{
        footBall.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        footBall.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}
```

When clicked the velocity of the ball becomes zero for a moment but the impulse should drive it up which is not happening. Please help me through this and ignore any ignorance because this is my first question and i am new to this.

Comment: I don't know how Swift works, but should you really be setting the `velocity` to 0 as well?

Comment: Yes, but why is what i don't know.

Comment: Have you set the mass of the football?

Comment: Yes, i tried setting the mass to 0.6 KG but that didn't help either.

Comment: And nothing still happens if you ramp up the impulse? Like `dy: 10000`

Comment: Doesn't matter what the value of impulse is, it only works for the first time when we click. After first click no matter how many times you click or tap, it is not affected by impulse. Maybe it is at rest or maybe something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that in the true branch you are applying a force, not an impulse.

Change:

```
footBall.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))
```

to

```
footBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 90))
```

Don't understand why you always zero the velocity either.

Comment: i wanted to ask a question that i wanted to apply impulse in a particular direction depending upon where on the footBall is tapped. Like when tapped on the right side of footBall, it should move towards left and up not only up. So how can i achieve that?

Comment: I think you pretty much said it there already. Calculate the center point of the ball in scene coordinates, compare touch point against that to see where it was touched, then apply dx / dy cgvector as per appropriate. To see if you touched the ball at all you can check nodesAtPoint.

Comment: Thank you @GOR. I will try that out.